# Aggregating a subquery with multiple OuterRefs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

For the following models:

```py
class Merchant(models.Model):
    ...

class Batch(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Merchant, ...)
    ...

class Tab(models.Model):
    is_void = models.BooleanField()
    ...

class Payment(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, ...)
    tab = models.ForeignKey(Tab, ...)
    payment = models.ForeignKey("self", ...)
    payment_type = models.CharField(choices=..., ...)
    status = models.CharField(choices=..., ...)
    amount = models.FloatField()
```

I'm trying to solve an N+1 selects issue. Currently, the code looks something like this, somewhat simplified - the code is really in a DRF serializer and does some other things:

```py
for payment in Payment.objects.filter(...):
    refunds_total = Payment.objects.filter(
        batch__merchant=obj.batch.merchant,
        payment=payment,
        payment_type="refund",
        status="success",
    ).exclude(
        tab__is_void=True,
    ).aggregate(
        total=Sum('amount')
    ).get('total', 0.0)
    # Do something with refunds_total.
```

The performance is really bad. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```py
refunds = Payment.objects.filter(
    batch__merchant=OuterRef("batch__merchant"),
    payment=OuterRef("id"),
    payment_type="refund",
    status="success",
).exclude(
    tab__is_void=True
).aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum("amount"), 0.0))
    ​
payments = Payment.objects.filter(
    ...
).annotate(total_refunds=Subquery(refunds))
```

But Django doesn't allow aggregating in a subquery, as aggregating immediately evaluates the QuerySet. I've tried two approaches. The first is following [this documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression). However, I'm not sure how I need to put the query together as there are multiple `OuterRefs` required. My first shot at a subquery looks like this:

```py
refunds = CustomerPayment.objects.filter( 
    batch__merchant=OuterRef("batch__merchant"), 
    payment=OuterRef("id"), 
    payment_type="refund", 
    status="success", 
).exclude( 
    tab__is_void=True 
).order_by().values( 
    "batch__merchant", "payment", 
).annotate(total_refunds=Coalesce(Sum("amount"), 0.0)).values("amount")
```

But however I try to get it working, it always returns multiple rows rather than single row with the total, so I can't use it in a subquery.

I've also tried making my own Subquery subclass but I couldn't put together anything that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the *how to do this with a subquery* question but I don't think you do need a subquery here.

Assuming you've defined a `Payment.payment.related_name = 'payments'` then [you can use conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation) to achieve the same results

```py
refunds = Payment.objects.annotate(
    total_refunds=Coalesce(Sum(
        'payments__amount',
        filter=(
            Q(payments__batch__merchant=F('batch__merchant'),
              payments__payment_type='refund',
              payments__status='success',
            ) & ~Q(
              payments__tab__is_void=True,
            )
        )
    ), 0.0)
)
```

This should result in the following SQL

```sql
SELECT
  payment.*,
  COALESCE(
    SUM(payments.amount) FILTER (
        WHERE payments_batch.merchant_id = payment_batch.merchant_id
        AND payments.payment_type = 'refund'
        AND payments.status = 'success'
        AND NOT (payments_tab.is_void = true)
    )
  ), 0.0) total_refunds
FROM payment
INNER JOIN batch ON (payment.batch_id = batch.id)
LEFT JOIN payment payments ON (payments.payment_id = payment.id)
INNER JOIN batch payments_batch ON (payments.batch_id = payments_batch.id)
INNER JOIN tab payments_tab ON (payments_tab.payment_id = payments.id)
GROUP BY payment.id
```

Which will likely perform better.

Comment: Using a subquery is often not the best performing way of doing things... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a subquery subclass, you just need to write the SQL:

```
class SubquerySum(Subquery):
    template = ''''(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(%(field)s), %(zero_value)s) 
                      FROM (%(subquery)s) _sum)'''

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, template=None, **extra_context):
        if 'field' not in extra_context and 'field' not in self.extra:
            if len(self.queryset._fields) > 1:
                raise FieldError('You must provide the field name, or have a single column')
            extra_context['field'] = self.queryset._fields[0]
        if 'zero_value' not in extra_context and 'zero_value' not in self.extra:
            extra_context['zero_value'] = 0
        return super().as_sql(compiler, connection, template=template, **extra_context)
```

You can use this wherever you'd normally use a Subquery:

```
refunds = Payment.objects.filter(
    batch__merchant=OuterRef("batch__merchant"),
    payment=OuterRef("id"),
    payment_type="refund",
    status="success",
).exclude(
    tab__is_void=True
)

payments = Payment.objects.filter(
    ...
).annotate(
    total_refunds=SubquerySum(refunds, zero_value=0.0, field='amount')
)
```

You may need to provide an `output_field` to the call, or maybe do a `.values('amount')` (which should enable omitting the field, zero value and output field).

```
SubquerySum(refunds.values('amount'))
```

But I'm not entirely sure if that will work.

More reading on subclasses of Subquery can be found at https://schinckel.net/2019/07/30/subquery-and-subclasses/.

Comment: This does indeed appear to work, thanks. I did need to add `output_field`.